# Converting the time from 24-hour notation to 12-hour notation and vice versa

Tags: c++

I cannot get it to convert to the 24 hour format. not what what I am missing. It will convert from 24 to 12 just fine. But when I try to do 12 to 24 it will not add to the hour to give a proper PM time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    void inputChoice(int& choice);
    void input12hours(int& hours, int& minutes, char& type);
    void input24hours(int& hours, int& minutes);
    void converTo12hours(int hours, int minutes);
    void converTo24hours(int hours, int minutes, char type);
    void output12hours(int hours, int minutes, char type);
    void output24hours(int hours, int minutes);
    
    int main() {
        int hours, minutes;
        char type;
        int choice;
        char repeatChoice;
        do {
            inputChoice(choice);
            switch (choice) {
            case 1:
                input24hours(hours, minutes);
                converTo12hours(hours, minutes);
                break;
            case 2:
                input12hours(hours, minutes, type);
                converTo24hours(hours, minutes, type);
                break;
            }
            //repeat confirmation
            cout << "\nDo you want to continue? [y/n]: ";
            cin >> repeatChoice;
        } 
        while (repeatChoice == 'y' || repeatChoice == 'Y');
        return 0;
    }
    
    void inputChoice(int& choice) {
        cout << "\n\n";
        cout << "1) Convert 24 hour to 12 hour" << endl;
        cout << "2) Convert 12 hour to 24 hour" << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice:";
        cin >> choice;
    }
    //get input in 12 hours format
    void input12hours(int& hours, int& minutes, char& type) {
        cout << "\nEnter hours:";
        cin >> hours;
        cout << "\nEnter minutes:";
        cin >> minutes;
        cout << "\nEnter AM/PM [A/P]:";
        cin >> type;
    }
    //get input in 24 hours format
    void input24hours(int& hours, int& minutes) 
    {
        cout << "\nEnter hours:";
        cin >> hours;
        cout << "\nEnter minutes:";
        cin >> minutes;
    }
    //convert 24 hour format to 12 hours format
    void converTo12hours(int hours, int minutes) 
    {
        char type;
        if (hours < 12) {
            type = 'A';
        }
        else {
            hours = hours - 12;
            if (hours == 0) 
            {
                hours = 12;
            }
            type = 'P';
        }
        output12hours(hours, minutes, type);
    }
    //convert 12 hour format to 24 hours format
    void converTo24hours(int hours, int minutes, char type) 
    {
        if (hours > 12)
    {
            hours = hours + 12;
                type = 'P';
            }
            
    //  output24hours(hours, minutes);
    //}
    //output in 12 hours
    void output12hours(int hours, int minutes, char type) 
    {
        cout << "\nThe time converted to 12 hour format is: " << hours << ":";
        //special handling for leading 0s on minutes
        cout.width(2);
        cout.fill('0');
        cout << minutes << " ";
        if (type == 'A') 
        {
            cout << "A.M." << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "P.M." << endl;
        }
    }
    //output in 24 hours
    void output24hours(int hours, int minutes) {
        cout << "\nThe time converted to 24 hour format is: " << hours << ":";
        //special handling for leading 0s on minutes
        cout.width(2);
        cout.fill('0');
        cout << minutes;
    }
```

Comment: In `converTo24hours` you have `if (hours > 12)`. Can you tell me how this is supposed to be true if the user has entered the time in 12-hour format?

Comment: `converTo12hours` does not works properly when `hours` is 0. Also `converTo24hours` commented cause a {} unbalance. Finally, you can use a debugger and unit tests to figure out the problem in your code. Any developer should have minimal debugging skill.

Comment: **Before writing code**, you should **think about the logic** that it is needed. As written, `converTo24hours` does not make sense at all. In 12 hours format, all hours are <= 12 so the only number for which you will add 12 is 12 itself which would give 24 which is never valid. Think about how you make the difference between 6 AM and 6 PM to get 6 and 18 respectively. Once it works for 1 to 11, then think about how to handle 12 AM or PM.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're overthinking it, here I had a little go at it and get some pretty good results, haven't checked all the edge cases yet.

Here's the function I came up with:

```
void output24hourtime(int hours, int mins, bool isPM)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    if (isPM)
    {
        if (hours == 12)
        {
            hours = -12 ;
        }
        ss << "The time in 24Hr is : "
            << hours + 12 << ":"
            << mins << std::endl;
        std::cout << ss.str();
    }
    else
    {
        ss << "The time in 24Hr is : "
            << hours << ":"
            << mins << std::endl;
        std::cout << ss.str();
    }
}
```

And here I implemented it quickly on top of one of your functions:

```
void input12hours(int& hours, int& minutes, char& type) {
    cout << "\nEnter hours:";
    cin >> hours;
    cout << "\nEnter minutes:";
    cin >> minutes;
    cout << "\nEnter AM/PM [A/P]:";
    cin >> type;

    //convert type to bool.
    bool isPM = false;
    if (type == 'P' || type == 'p')
    {
        isPM = true;
    }
    //call my function to output 24 hrs time
    output24hourtime(hours, minutes, isPM);
}
```